Is there a safe way to overwrite a stream delta table?
I need to fully overwrite a stream delta table using PySpark without messing with the checkpoint, is there any safe way to do this? I do no need to keep any version from previous delta.

"checkmark" button guide

You can run a delete statement on the delta table. You can find the syntax here (https://docs.delta.io/0.4.0/delta-update.html#delete-from-a-table) and it wouldn't affect the checkpoints.
